# Are there different kinds of MD5 sum generation?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, md5, md5sum

I'm wondering if there are different kinds of MD5 implementation that generate different MD5 sums.

I have a database with it's primary key which is MD5 summed to produce another key.

Let's take for example, the value of the primary key is **1315517**, and it's MD5 sum is **012DFF3A19270B1965A0D19A7172562F**, which is produced from **http://onlinemd5.com/**

However, when I look into the database, it said that it's MD5 sum is **1e2b5aa4128156aa3dc82b6d7402e935**.

I've tried to reverse the MD5 sum of **1e2b5aa4128156aa3dc82b6d7402e935** but it seems that nobody had computed the value of the MD5 sum.

Comment: Note that MD5 is defined for byte strings as input. If you have strings or numbers as input, then there are different ways of turning them into bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MD5 is a single specification and every implementation must produce the same output for the same bytes and this is where the differences come in. The string that you see has different byte representations depending on the chosen encoding.

It is also unclear how the database engine converts the primary key (I assume it is an integer) into bytes. It can take it as a string (note the encoding), but it can also try to pack the integer into bytes and then it is a question whether big-endian or little-endian is used.

Comment: I'm not going to solve the MD5 differences for you, but as a starting point, the website probably uses UTF-8 encoding and the database uses maybe "Latin1" or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That's what I thought with MD5 sum, is that different implementations should produce the same output.